# Linux outputs joining from LSBLK and DF

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, disk

I need to merge two outputs in Linux. This:

```
lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | grep -v "fd0" | grep -v "loop" | grep -v "sr0" | grep -v "hdc" | grep -v "cdrom"
```

In a result I have:

```
sda   sda                   53687091200
sda1  └─sda1                53684994048
dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 /
sdb   sdb                 2147483648000
sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424
dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker
dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd
sdc   sdc                  536870912000
sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424
dm-0    └─ssdVG-ssdLV      536866717696 /dockerssd
```

And this:

```
df --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay} | sed -e /^Filesystem/d | awk '{print $6 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}'
```

In a result I have:

```
/ /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8110496 40591632 17%
/dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214133656 274642488 44%
/dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83278236 1385191240 6%
/var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76046204 412729940 16%
```

So, I want to Join via these points /, /var/lib/docker, /dockerhdd, /dockerssd.
Important! I want to check this in another place, where we will have another mount points. Also I have to save structure of first output without sorting.

In a result I have to receive something like this:

```
sda   sda                   53687091200
sda1  └─sda1                53684994048
dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 / /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8110496 40591632 17%
sdb   sdb                 2147483648000
sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424
dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76046204 412729940 16%
dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83278236 1385191240 6%
sdc   sdc                  536870912000
sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424
dm-0    └─ssdVG-ssdLV      536866717696 /dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214133656 274642488 44%
```

I implemented something like this:

```
lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | egrep -v "fd0|ram|loop|sr0|hdc|cdrom" |
while read kname name size mountpoint ; do
    printf '%-5s' "$kname"
    printf '%-20s' "$name"
    printf '%30s' "$size"
    printf '%-10s' " "
    if [ "$mountpoint" != "" ] ; then
        df --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay} | sed -e /^Filesystem/d | awk '{print $6 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}' | grep "$mountpoint "
    else
        echo
    fi
done
```

It works, and I am receiving needed result:

```
sda   sda                   53687091200
sda1  └─sda1                53684994048
dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 / /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8110496 40591632 17%
sdb   sdb                 2147483648000
sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424
dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76046204 412729940 16%
dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83278236 1385191240 6%
sdc   sdc                  536870912000
sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424
dm-0    └─ssdVG-ssdLV      536866717696 /dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214133656 274642488 44%
```

But only on `Ubuntu`, it works.
On `CentOS6` , I see another picture.
`df` command on `CentOS 6`:

```
df
Filesystem           1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_root
                      51475068 5661336  43192292  12% /
tmpfs                   957140       0    957140   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               487652   82688    379364  18% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_home
                      77349888  294352  73119692   1% /home
```

I need to receive via following `order`:

```
Mount point, Filesystem, Used, Available, Use%
```

But I am receiving:

```
 /dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_root
 51475068 43192316 12% /
/boot /dev/sda1 82688 379364 18%
 /dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_home
 77349888 73119692 1% /home
```

There are a problem with columns ?

I have two questions. First, maybe we could resolve my problem with Joining of two these outputs via `AWK`. Could You help me please ? Could You help me with one-liner ?
Second: How I can make the same output of `DF` on `CentOS6` and `Ubuntu` ?

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday?

Comment: Yes, but I am improved. Please look more. I found how to do this. But I need little fix in `DF`, how to do this

Comment: You can format the output from df with -o

Comment: @RamanSailopal It works only in new versions. In `CentOS 6` we don't have this

Comment: @RamanSailopal Also, Your `AWK` yesterday did not help. But Your answer was interesting, thanks

Comment: Considered looking at the man-page for `df`?  `df -P` will deliver consistent (identical) output between Centos6 and a modern Ubuntu.